NED file located in MyProject/src cannot be seen in MyProject/simulation/package.ned
I have compound module "ExtSwitch" in src folder of my project. When I try to extend this module in NED file (simulation/package.ned) there is error "no such component "ExtSwitch".
I have other Simple module also in rsc folder which can be seen.
I have no idea what I can try else. Please help me
In Properties I set 'src' and 'simulation' in NED sorce folders.
